# External authentication in a Django app

Tags: python, django

As the title says, I'm developing a Django app which uses another API to authenticate the user. The external API is quite simple and returns a certificate if the user is properly authenticated. My app should not keep any user's information, except it's certificate and id (which I'm keeping as session variables).

As a drawback of this implementation, I'm not using Django’s authentication system and all the practical methods it offers, like to check if the user `is_authenticated`, `is_anonymous` or to get user's permissions.

As the user must be logged to access some pages of my app, I must aswell ask him/her to log in so that he/she could continue. Therefore, using `@login_required` would be handful.

I must also create a Access Control module to check permissions and to allow access to some restricted areas of the app according to groups of users (common users, admins, etc.).

Do you guys know how could I customize Django's authentication system to handle all theses issues?

Answer (score 2):

You have to keep logged in user inside your `request` so just log him without authentication

```
from django.contrib.auth import login

def authenticate_by_api_view(request):
    certificate = do_the_magic()

    if certificate_valid(certificate):
        user = User()
        #you can set ID here and save the user to the DB then
        login(request, user)
```

If you don't want to save user at all you can take a look at the [django-lazysignup](https://github.com/danfairs/django-lazysignup) project or use rather [Django sessions framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/sessions/)

Comment: At the moment, I'm using Django sessions, but it does not give me the facilities to check if user is authenticated. I have to manual check session attributes everytime I call a method. Besides, it's a bit hard to handle private urls that the user must only have access if logged. And you are right, I don't want to save any user.

Comment: if I were you and I did not not want to use *lazysignup* I would just save the user with some temp data - I would add eventually some task that would remove users whose *last login date* is before today then